# How to sort pivot columns in Looker Studio in Viewer mode?

Tags: sorting, pivot-table, google-data-studio

If it's a table, all one has to do is click the column's title or right click and choose Sort By:

[[image: Sorting table1]

How can the same be achieved to pivot tables?

[image: Unsortable pivot table]

[image: Adding table or pivot]